# Оптимизация путем работы с небезопасным программированием

Tags: c#, unsafe

Очень интересует ответы на некоторые вопросы:

1. Правда ли, что если итерировать простой массив чисел и получать его элементы через индексацию немного не оптимизировано, чем получить указатель на этот массив и итерировать его игнорируя исключение `IndexOutOfRangeException` (То есть, мы пропускаем некоторые проверки)

К примеру:

```
int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
fixed (int* ptrValue = &array[0])
{
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < array.Length; iterator++)
        Console.Write($"{*(iterator + ptrValue)} ");
}
```

2. Какой код оптимизированнее и почему?

```
internal readonly struct ValueFirst<T>
{
    internal readonly T[] _pointer;
    
    public ValueFirst(T[] values)
    {
        _pointer = values;
    }
    
    public ref T this[int index]
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        get => ref Unsafe.Add(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(_pointer), (uint)index);
    }
}
```

или

```
internal readonly struct ValueSecond<T>
{
    internal readonly T[] _pointer;

    public ValueSecond(T[] values)
    {
        _pointer = values;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _pointer[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Если код не будет запутан и компилятор получит гарантию невыхода за пределы диапазона в цикле, то он выбросит проверки границ массива сам при автоматической оптимизации. Так что использование прямого доступа к памяти может оказаться не оправданным, так как для него требуется фиксация массива в памяти, для обращения через индекс - нет, что дает больше свободы проводить свои оптимизации в памяти сборщику мусора. Но реальный ответ кроется в простых тестах производительности, запустите бенчмарк.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Сложно ответить ибо "немного не оптимизировано" понятие расплывчатое. Оптимизация должна быть уместной, и думать о ней стоит **ТОЛЬКО** когда упёрлись в неприемлемую производительность программы.
2. Здесь поможет ответить [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), но, учитывая что индексатор в ValueFirst по сути транслируется в это:

   ```
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld !0[] valuetype ValueFirst`1<!T>::_pointer
    IL_0006: call !!0& [System.Memory]System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal::GetArrayDataReference<!T>(!!0[])
    IL_000b: ldarg.1
    IL_000c: conv.u
    IL_000d: call !!0& [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::Add<!T>(!!0&, native uint)
    IL_0012: ret
   ```

а индексатор в ValueSecond в это:

```
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld !0[] valuetype ValueSecond`1<!T>::_pointer
    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: ldelem !T
    IL_000c: ret
```

*предположу*, что 2-й вариант будет работать быстрее, так как в нём нет вызовов методов.

Comment: IL не даст прямого ответа на вопрос о производительности кода. Смотрите лучше в релизный ассемблер.